# What is the difference between cloudfoundry buildpack and compiler?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Are they operating system specific? Where can I find windows buildpacks?

reference: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/understand-buildpacks.html#detection

Answer (score 0):

They are OS specific. reference: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/stack-association.html

Answer (score 0):

[Buildpacks](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/) provide framework and runtime support for apps. Whereas Compiler is to compile your code.

You will not use **compiler** in CloudFoundry, with the fact that you will run only compiled-codes in Cloudfoundry

Comment: `You will not use compiler in CloudFoundry, with the fact that you will run only compiled-codes in Cloudfoundry` That's not strictly true. You can push code & have the buildpack compile it for you, so in that case you'd need a compiler (Golang is one example). Fortunately it's easy as a user because the buildpack is responsible for installing the compiler for you, so while you need it, you don't have to think about it. You also don't have to run compiled code. You can run scripts too. That's splitting hairs though :)